# semtimedop in linux: Possible reasons for EAGAIN in semtimedop

Tags: linux, shared-memory

We are working on a project where we are using shared memory to transfer image & data. The design also ensures that the writer/consumer reads the information only after successful write by the writer/producer.
But sometimes we are observing that the reader fails to read the information( its a very very rare case ) & there is a time out.

Any suggestions/clue what could have caused the problem.

Comment: Isn't the operation just timing out which means that sometimes your writer hasn't finished writing before the timeout occurs?  Isn't that why you set the time out?

Comment: As told, we are ensuring from the design that we start the read only after the write is completed.

Comment: and then a timeout would occur when the write hasn't finished and the operation would return EAGAIN.  So what exactly _is_ the problem?

Comment: dave, I think you didnt get the point. Write is completed before the Read starts & that is ensured.

Comment: And how do you ensure that?